# Monitoring changes on SFTP server with WinSCP and batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sftp, winscp

I want to monitor our SFTP to send email to us if a file is added. For now I tried to make a condition with `if`/`else` with a batch script, but the batch environment does not accept my condition.

I am new with batch and automation, so what I tried to do is synchronise the SFTP file with a local file in first place and run a batch schedule to try to synchronise again; if it does then it is going to send na email (I did not make the script for the email at the moment and to be honest I do not know how to do so for now), if it did not synchronise then exit script.

Here is my script:

```
option batch on
option confirm off
open sftp://x@sftp.x/ -privatekey=privateKey.ppk -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 x"
option transfer binary
if synchronize local "C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\x\x" "/x/x/rx" (
ECHO nouveau fichier ajouter au repertoir
)
else (ECHO aucun nouveau fichier exit
)
```

Here is the error:

> ```
> Commande inconnue 'if'.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add [`-preview` switch to your `synchronize` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize#preview) to make it only check for changes, instead of actually synchronizing the files.
- Add [`option failonnomatch on`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option#failonnomatch) to your script to make the `synchronize` command report no differences as an error.

  ```
  option failonnomatch on
  synchronize -preview local "C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\x\x" "/x/x/rx"
  ```
- In the actual batch file, [check WinSCP exit code](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#result) to determine, if there are any differences or not. Something like this:

  ```
  winscp.com /script=script.txt /log=script.log
  if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Nothing to synchronize or other problem
  ) else (
    echo There are files to synchronize
  )
  ```

  *If you want to send an email, see WinSCP guide for [Emailing script results](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_email).*